# Class node has no member named

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this function declared

```
template<class ItemType>
LinkedBag<ItemType> LinkedBag<ItemType>::bagUnion(LinkedBag<ItemType> otherBag)
{
    LinkedBag<ItemType> unionBag; // create a new Bag

    Node<ItemType>* curPtr = headPtr; // get a pointer to the beginning of the invoking bags list
    for(int i=0; i<getCurrentSize(); i++) // for each item in the list ...
    {   
        unionBag.add( curPtr->getItem() ); // add the item to the new bag
        curPtr = curPtr->getNext(); // cycle to the next item (needed for linked list)
    }

   curPtr = otherBag.headPtr;
   for(int j=0;j<otherBag.getCurrentSize(); j++)
   {
      unionBag.add(curPtr->getItems()); //add the item to unionBag
      curPtr = curPtr->getNext();// cycle to the next Item
   }
return unionBag;
}
```

This is the error I got

> BagTester.cpp:70:56:   required from here
>   LinkedBag.cpp:244:7: error: 'class Node >' has no member named 'getItems()'

Comment: It sounds like the error message is telling you what the problem is already... I suggest you listen to your compiler.

Comment: The problem is on the second loop unionBag.add(curPtr->getItems()); "has no member named 'getItems()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo. You wrote `getItems` instead of `getItem`.

Please, listen to the error messages and check your spelling before you post a question to Stack Overflow!